# how to Show confirmation msgbox when data is successfully inserted into database using detailsview in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Show confirmation msgbox when data is successfully inserted into database using detailsview in asp.net ?

Comment: You want a confirmation when data is already inserted? I assume you want a dialog to show that the data is successfully inserted into database: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/
Confirmation would mean that the user could cancel the action.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET has no available MsgBox. You can use alert from JavaScript.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "MyScript", "alert('successfully!');", True)
```

for ItemCreated:

```
Protected Sub DetailsView1_ItemCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "MyScript", "alert('successfully!');", True)
End Sub
```

```
<asp:detailsview id="DetailsView1"
...
onitemcreated="DetailsView1_ItemCreated"   
runat="server"></asp:detailsview>
```